# VB Function with that returns the new value of an input

Tags: vba, function

I am trying to set up a very basic VBA funcion which takes 2 inputs; temp and time, then spits out the new value of temp when time is multiplied by 2. Note that temp = time*100.

It will look something like this:

```
Function newVal(temp,time)

    time = time*2
    newVal = temp

End Function
```

So, for example, if time is 1 originally then temp equals 100. But now I want to spit out what temp would equal if time is multiplied by 2 (i.e. 200, in a new cell), but leaving the original cells the same (i.e. time =1 and temp = 100).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods accept parameters in two ways, by value `ByVal` and by reference `ByRef`.

The default way in VBA is `ByRef` therefore if you ommit the any of the `ByVal` or `ByRef` keywords in your method's parameter declaration (like your example above), it will be passed by reference.

What that means? It means any changes made to the passed argument, will be made against the original value.

To avoid this you need to pass the arguments by value.

ByRef example:

```
Function newVal(temp,time)
    time = time*2  'This changes the original value of time
    newVal = temp
End Function
```

ByVal example:

```
Function newVal(ByVal temp As Long, ByVal time as Long)
    newVal = temp * (time * 2)
End Function
```

There are a few exceptions to the rule, for example objects can only be passed by reference.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx).

Comment: Thank You so much!!! I was actually using byval, but I had the time = time*2 on a separate line which stopped the function from working.

Comment: The only problem is that temp is already linked to time in my spreadsheet, so the formula already exists. Would you know how to overcome this?

Comment: So, to clairfy, I am essentially running a scenario for when time = 2. In the sheet if i put time = 2, temp will automatically become 200. So can I achieve this scneario without including the formula inside the function??

Comment: Not too sure I understand the problem, but you can return only time * 2 scrapping temp altogether? `newVal = time * 2`